# Load testing WMS capabilities for GeoServer instance?

Tags: geoserver, wms, performance, ubuntu

I would like to load test the WMS capabilities for our GeoServer instance. How should I go about this?

Server is running 64 bit ubuntu 14.04, Oracle Java 8, and geoserver 2.7.2

I know I could simply post the link to social media and have a bunch of people blast away at it but I don't know what to use to actually track performance metrics like the quantity of simultaneous users vs, load times, latency, and errors.

Ideally there would be both client side and server side tools to help track this and simulate a large user load.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [GeoSolutions GeoServer Training TOC](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/)
- [Advanced GeoServer Config](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/index.html)
- [Enterprise set up recommendations](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/enterprise/index.html)
- [Search for Performance on our blog](http://www.geo-solutions.it/search/performance)
- [Blog Post on Marlin Renderer](http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/developerss-corner-achieving-extreme-geoserver-scalability-with-the-new-marlin-vector-rasterizer/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Link fixed and more ones added on the way :)